# Error invoking remote method 'ELECTRON_BROWSER_DESKTOP_CAPTURER_GET_SOURCES'. Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to develop a small windows app with **Electron**, I installed everything and then started working with a tutorial. What I'm trying to do is take a screenshot of my desktop when pressing a button, but I'm getting an error that says `Error invoking remote method 'ELECTRON_BROWSER_DESKTOP_CAPTURER_GET_SOURCES': Failed to get sources.`

HTML Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div style="padding-top: 75px; text-align:center">
        <label id="screenShotMessage"></label>
        <button id="screenShotTaker" class="btn btn-info">Take screenshot</button>
    </div>
    <script src="render.js">            
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Render Js:

```
const { remote, desktopCapturer } = require('electron'); // Renderer process modules
const { screen } = remote; // Main process modules
const electronScreen = remote.screen;
const shell = remote.shell;

const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');

const screenshot = document.getElementById('screenShotTaker');
const screenshotMessage = document.getElementById('screenShotMessage');

screenshot.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    screenshotMessage.textContent = "Gathering screen...";
    const thumbSize = determineScreenShot();
    let options = { types: ['screen'], thumnailSize: thumbSize };

    desktopCapturer.getSources(options, function (error, sources) {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log(sources);
        sources.forEach(function (source) {
            if (source.name === "Entire Screen" || source.name === "Screen 1") {
                const screenshotPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), "screenshot.jpg");
                fs.writeFile(screenshotPath, source.thumbnail.toPng(), function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err.message);
                    }
                    shell.openExternal('file://' + screenshotPath);
                    var message = "Saved screenshot to: " + screenshotPath;
                    screenshotMessage.textContent = message;
                });
            }
        });
    });
});

function determineScreenShot() {
    const screenSize = electronScreen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;
    const maxDimension = Math.max(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
    return {
        width: maxDimension * window.devicePixelRatio,
        height: maxDimension * window.devicePixelRatio
    };
}
```

Main Js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = require("electron");
//main process
const path = require("path");
const url = require("url");
let win;

function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800, height: 600, webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        } });
    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'main.html'),
        protocol: 'file',
        slashes: true
    }));

    win.on('close', () => {
        win = null;
    });

    win.openDevTools();
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (win === null) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

The error happens when `desktopCapturer` tries to get the sources. I'm not sure why and I've not found any other solution for this. Thanks

Comment: to get a screenshot there is another api `Wincontents.capturePage()`

Comment: try removing `const { screen } = remote;` what is the purpose of this?

Comment: @namila007 yeah I was using it before it has no meaning. Does Wincontents.CapturePage() allows you yo captue the entire screen or just the app windows content?

Comment: it can capture on selected browserWindows .

Comment: you mean just what the browser shows?  @namila007

Comment: yes, can capture what sees on the relevant browser window